# Spreading a data.frame and adding columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have this `data.frame` format (resulting from an `lm` summary `matrix`):

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(effect = rnorm(3), effect_se = runif(3,0,0.2), effect_p.value = runif(3,0,1), factor_name = paste0("F",1:3))
```

And I'd like to `spread` it to this format:

```
spread.df <- data.frame(F1.effect = df$effect[1], F1.effect_se = df$effect_se[1], F1.effect_p.value = df$effect_p.value[1],
                        F2.effect = df$effect[2], F2.effect_se = df$effect_se[2], F2.effect_p.value = df$effect_p.value[2],
                        F3.effect = df$effect[3], F3.effect_se = df$effect_se[3], F3.effect_p.value = df$effect_p.value[3])
```

What would be the `tidyr` way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to `gather` into 'long' format, `unite` the columns and `spread`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   gather(key, val, effect:effect_p.value) %>%
   unite(fname,factor_name, key) %>%
   spread(fname, val)
```

If the column names needs to be in a particular order, then `mutate` the 'fname' column by converting to `factor` with `levels` specified in the expected order

Answer (score 0):

I came to a similar answer to @akrun but I would recommend not doing the final spread. It achieves the result you asked for sure, but I bet you willl find your data easier to work with in the “long” and “tidy” format.